# Is there an interpolating quote-like word list operator?

Tags: perl, operators

`qw{}` is a nice-looking way for writing lists. Is there a similar that interpolates the words, i.e. expands variables? [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) does not seem to mention any.

Comment: No, there is no built-in, but many of us write our own.  Also for the two kinds of `ql()` needs for lists of lines.  I use `deQ` for a `q()` version and `deQQ` for a `qq` version of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no built-in, but many of us write our own.

Also for the two kinds of `ql()` needs for lists of lines.  I use `deQ` for a `q()` version and `deQQ` for a `qq` version of those that works with Perl’s “hasta” operator:

```
sub dequeue($$) {
    my($leader, $body) = @_;
    $body =~ s/^\s*\Q$leader\E ?//gm;
    return $body;
}

sub deQ($) {
    my $text = $_[0];
    return dequeue q<|Q|>,  $text;
}

sub deQQ($) {
    my $text = $_[0];
    return dequeue qq<|QQ|>, $text;
}
```

That lets me use stuff like this:

```
sub compile($) {
    my $CODE = shift();
    my $wrap = deQQ<<"END_OF_COMPILATION";
                |QQ|
                |QQ|    use warnings qw[FATAL all];
                |QQ|    no  warnings "utf8";
                |QQ|
                |QQ|    sub { 
                |QQ|           my \$_ = shift; 
                |QQ|           $CODE; 
                |QQ|           return \$_;
                |QQ|    }
                |QQ|
END_OF_COMPILATION

    return eval $wrap;

}
```

or

```
        my $sorter = new Unicode::Collate::
                            upper_before_lower  => 1,
                            preprocess          => \&reduce_for_sorting,
                            entry               => deQ<<'END_OF_OVERRIDE'
             |Q|
             |Q|        005B 006E 002E ; [.0200.0020.0002.0391] # [n.
             |Q|        005B           ; [.0220.0020.0002.0392] # [
             |Q|        005D           ; [.0225.0020.0002.0395] # ]
             |Q|
END_OF_OVERRIDE
```

See how that works?

Comment: I see how it works, but not why it is necessary. A heredoc already interpolates, so why wrap it in `deQQ`?

Comment: @Tim: It’s wrapped so that it stands out and doesn’t count leading or trailing whitespace or the standout leader in the resulting string. It makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I see; that's clever.

Can you write your own `qqw()` to imitate the `qw()` syntax, or is the closest I'm going to get `qqw "string"` with a `qqw($)` sub?

Comment: @Tim: Thank you. :) In Perl, all things are possible but not all are expedient. So yes, you *can,* but you wouldn’t want to look at yourself in the morning. To get your pick-your-quotes behavior, you’d have to go enter the haunted madhouse known as source filters. Even the `use version` pragma’s `qv()` version-quoting function doesn’t do this, although as you see it does do other tricks.  I think you should be happy for now with `sub qqw($) { my @w = split /[\h\v]+/, $_[0]; shift @w while @w && !length($w[0]); return @w }`. Later decide whether Extraördinary Measures are truly called for.

Answer (score 6):

You can sprinkle `qw()` in the midst of a "regular" list.  I sometimes write code like this:

```
my @command = (
    qw(cat arg1 arg2),
    $arg3,
    qw(arg4 arg5 arg6),
    "$arg7 $arg8",
    # ...
);
```

Comment: This is actually the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on ysth's answer:

```
sub qqw($) { split /\s+/, $_[0] }

my @list = qqw"$var interpolating string";
```

Caveats: I don't know how leading and trailing whitespace are handled. Furthermore, the prototype should make sure that `qqw` does not consume multiple comma-separated values like sub calls normally do, but you should check that to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
split(' ', "$var interpolating string ");
```

Comment: Doesn't fulfill the _nice-looking way_ criterion :) tchrist's post resulted in such a sub.