# How to pass parameter to perl qw[]?

Tags: perl

I am customizing an open source Perl script for some db backup. I don't have much knowledge in Perl. Can someone tell me how will i pass a parameter to `qw[]`?

for example the original code is like this

```
@selected_databases  = qw[testdb1 testdb2 testdb3];
```

i want to convert it to something like below

```
$_dblist = "testdb1 testdb2 testdb3";
@selected_databases  = qw[$_dblist];
```

but it is not working. Can someone tell me how will I pass a variable to qw[]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an interpolating quote-like word list operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771428/is-there-an-interpolating-quote-like-word-list-operator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`qw` does not support interpolation. As per the [perl-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). As such, you cannot do that, it will not work. To achieve what you are looking to do, use the `split` function.

```
$_dblist = "testdb1 testdb2 testdb3";
@selected = split(' ', $_dblist);
```

Comment: Edited `split`'s argument to match qw's behaviour.

Comment: @ikegami - While yes the perldoc does say that `qw` is roughly equivalent to `split(" " ...` a few short test show that you can use and that `qw` will accept any whitespace as it's delimiter ( and multiple ones in conjunction ).

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, The difference between `split ' '` and `split /\s+/` is in how leading white space is treated. `split /\s/` iis worse that what you had originally.